# Trying to access webcam in html5: Firefox works, Chrome and Opera don't

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, webcam, getusermedia

I'm trying to access my webcam through javascript. When I use the following minimal example below, I would expect to see at least a popup, asking for permission to access the webcam.

This works on Firefox, but not on Chrome or Opera (all latest versions).

Obviously the actual webcam content is not yet displayed here, I'm merely initiating `GetUserMedia` (or its browser specific variant) but even that already doesn't work. I'm not getting 'yep' or 'nope' popup (except on Firefox).

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script>
function OnSuccess(stream) { alert('yes') }
function OnError(error) { alert('nope') }

function OnLoad()
{
  navigator.anyGetUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
   || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
   || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
   || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  navigator.anyGetUserMedia( {video:true, audio:false}, OnSuccess, OnError );
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='OnLoad()'>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the strange thing is, when I use the exact same code on jsfiddle, it *does* work.
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/999anu81/ (if you have a webcam, this should ask permission to access it)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has some restrictions on when getUserMedia is allowed to avoid pages badgering people, IIRC.  Attach it to a button instead of using onload, and it should work better.